# WM_GETFONT returns type LRESULT instead of expected HFONT

Tags: c++, winapi

Doing `HFONT childfont = SendMessage (childwin, WM_GETFONT, NULL, NULL);` results in the error "invalid conversion from 'LRESULT' to 'HFONT__*'" when [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632624%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that the return type is HFONT. What is the proper return type for this function? Should I just use LRESULT or is there something special I have to do because my program will come back and bite me later if I don't do it?

Comment: You could also use the `GetWindowFont` macro that does the cast for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SendMessage` is a Swiss army knife: it does a lot of different things, all of which return various types of values.  Since C does not support overloaded return values (remember that the Win32 API is a C API), it has to return a generic `LRESULT` type.

So, you need to cast the result to the actual type.  The documentation states that it this message returns an `HFONT`, so you must cast the result to an `HFONT`:

```
HFONT childFont = (HFONT)SendMessage(childWin, WM_GETFONT, ...);
```

Alternatively, you can use the macro `GetWindowFont()` defined in the header file `<WindowsX.h>`, which includes a lot of utility macros:

```
// From WindowsX.h.  SNDMSG is a macro which expands to either SendMessage or
// AfxSendMessage.
#define GetWindowFont(hwnd) FORWARD_WM_GETFONT((hwnd), SNDMSG)
#define FORWARD_WM_GETFONT(hwnd, fn) \
    (HFONT)(UINT_PTR)(fn)((hwnd), WM_GETFONT, 0L, 0L)

// Example usage:
HFONT childFont = GetWindowFont(childWin);
```

Comment: That's some nice return type casting going on. I was just looking at it in the header. I can't find it for the life of me in MSDN.

Answer (score 4):

Since `SendMessage` is used for many, many purposes, it can't have the perfect return type for everything. In this case, you have to cast it to the type you need:

```
HFONT childfont = reinterpret_cast<HFONT>(SendMessage(...));
```

In the handler for `WM_GETFONT`, you'd expect to see something like the equivalent of this:

```
HFONT whateverFont;
...
return (LRESULT)whateverFont;
```

So casting back to the `HFONT` it was originally is ok.